# Variables in files included by bootstrap.php in cakephp seem not to be defined

Tags: cakephp, bootstrapping

I am including a file in bootstrap.php like this

```
include('files/settings.php');
```

The settings.php file contains

```
    $var= "value";
    function myFunction(){
        echo "myFunction echo";
    }
```

Now, in one of my templates I try to use the function and the variable.
The problem is that while the function is working as expected, when I try to print the variable i get a "not defined" notice.

I use CakePHP 2.1.3

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When defined like this, the variable is a global.

You have to import it in the function where you want to use it, like this:

```
function globalVariableUsingFunction() {
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
```

More info in the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

EDIT: Based on the comments, this is CakePHP specific behavior: from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cake-php/9j07EXTuoVY)

> File bootstrap is included in method Configure::__loadBootstrap() so
>   You have to mark Your global variables by keyword 'global' as global -
>   otherwise they are valid only in scope inside of above mentioned
>   method.

So, modifying your bootstrap.php like this

```
global $var= "value";
function myFunction(){
    echo "myFunction echo";
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: OK, I can understand that it might be a problem of visibility in the context of layout regarding my variable, but bootstrap.php shouldn't be the place where I can define the constants of my app too? I can not reach them eithere.

Comment: While it doesn't work for me not even using $GLOBALS['var'], it might be another problem..

Comment: @Radu are you sure the file containing the variables gets properly included?

Comment: Yes, like I said in the description of my problem, I can make use of the function but not of the var. They are in the same file.. It's not a mistype problem - I verified that too..